# RGBa vs Opacity (Specifically BBC Slider)

Tags: css, opacity, rgba

I am currently wondering which is the best CSS property to use, Opacity or RGBa? More specifically I am trying to recreate something similar to the famous [BBC Home page slider](http://www.bbc.co.uk/), and it got me thinking why they use Opacity.

In my version I have came across using the following two versions of code:

```
.left-button {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat; //FALLBACK
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat;
}
```

or

```
.left-button {
    background: #fff url('../images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat; //FALLBACK
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Obviously the second one makes the actual button image opaque too, which is why I assume the BBC has made separate buttons and background masks for the buttons (which in my opinion is unnecessary additional markup).

I'd like to use the first version with RGBa though. Would anyone care to point out why one is better than the other and if there is any compatibility issues I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

`Opacity` is inherited to all child items, `RGBa` is not. If a child item has a lesser or no opacity, use RGBa.

IE8 and lower does not support RGBa, so you may need an opacity back-up plan.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is "better" because they do different things, so it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

`opacity` sets the opacity for the entire element and all of its contents (text, inline images, etc). `RGBa` is a way to define a color with a certain level of alpha transparency.

So let's say you have a `div`:

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

This will make the entire `div` and its contents ("Hello!") 50% opaque:

```
div {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Whereas this will make just the background of the `div` 50% opaque, while leaving the text at 100% opaque pure white:

```
div {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}
```